# How to debug this "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target" error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When i write the following code, I get the `Application tried to push a nil view controller on target` error.

```
BOOL isboyWithGlass;
isboyWithGlass=TRUE;
NSLog(@"%@",isboyWithGlass);
```

can anyone tell me how to remove this error while i am using the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOOL while printing it always takes it as int

So print it like

```
NSLog(@"%d",isboyWithGlass);
```

It will return as 1 (If it is yes)  or 0 (If it is no)

If you want to print it as string then

```
NSLog(@"%@", (isboyWithGlass ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to print integer flat of BOOL then used @"%d" to your code other vise it's gone in autorelease pool

Comment: BOOL return either 0 or 1 that's why it's gone in